# Improving face recognition with cob_people_detection?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am using the most excellent [cob_people_detection](http://wiki.ros.org/cob_people_detection) package under ROS Indigo and Ubuntu 14.04 together with an MS Kinect (Xbox 360) at 640x480 resolution.   I have only 5 people so far in the database with 40 images per person taken at different angles but the face recognizer often assigns the wrong label to one of those same people standing in front of the camera.  I've tried Fischer faces, EigenFaces, and LDA2D but performance does not change much.

Does anyone have any suggestions for improving recognition performance?

Thanks!
patrick

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/243015/improving-face-recognition-with-cob_people_detection?/) by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 4046 on 2016-09-02

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [curranw](https://answers.ros.org/users/17736/curranw/) on 2016-09-02**:
I tend to use the [people](http://wiki.ros.org/face_detector?distro=kinetic) package for this type of work. It uses the opencv haar classifiers, which are pretty good. There's many of them and you can switch them out easily.

**Comment by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on 2016-09-03**:
Thanks @curranw, but as far as I can tell, the people package only does face **detection** whereas my issue is with face **recognition**.  The cob_people_detection package actually does a great job at face detection (as well as head detection even when the face is not visible).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have some general techniques that seem to work with haar classifiers. The same may work for you.

If I'm getting too many false positives, a great tool to use is the opencv_createsamples executable. It allows you to generate many additional positive samples by stretching, rotating and zooming in/out positives. It also throws these samples in other negative images, so your classifier learns to ignore backgrounds.  [Here's](http://memememememememe.me/post/training-haar-cascades/) a good tutorial for it.

If I'm not getting enough true positives, I simply need more positives examples. These could be just brute-forcing more examples, or trying more feature-rich positive examples.

---

Originally posted by [curranw](https://answers.ros.org/users/17736/curranw/) with karma: 211 on 2016-09-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on 2016-09-05**:
Thanks @curranw -- this might also work for face recognition so I'll give it a try.

**Comment by [amal](https://answers.ros.org/users/35597/amal/) on 2018-07-12**:
Hi,
Can you please help me how can I use this tutorial for cob people detection . Thanks for advance